# How to word-wrap headers in a vertical table (transposed table)?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

We are using the responsive tables as described here: http://dbushell.com/demos/tables/rt_05-01-12.html .

[image]

It transposes the table by creating a vertical table with a fixed left column. The transposed header row,
however, is not wrapped on white space and unnecessarily widens the table.

> For transposing, the trick is to use `display: inline-block;` on the table rows and
>   `white-space: nowrap;` on the table body.

Any solutions to enable wrapping in the header row?

**JsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/ckaodhz1/**

Code for the above trick:

```
table thead { display: block; float: left; }
table tbody {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
table thead tr { display: block; }
table th { display: block; }
table tbody tr { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }
```

Comment: Hi @pratyush  you can try with  word-break: break-word

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<th>` tag for all the headers.

Then you can use `word-wrap: break-word;` for the `<th>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ellipsis. try this

```
.graham tr td:first-child{
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  width:50px;
}
```

Comment: the ellipsis solution won't help because 1. it will require fixing the column widths, 2. the header names are not obvious as one might confuse "operating profit" with "operating margin" in case of ellipsis.